# What GeckoView build should you use on Android?

Tags: android, geckoview

[I am currently browsing the Mozilla maven GeckoView directory for Android.](https://maven.mozilla.org/?prefix=maven2/org/mozilla/geckoview/)

I have to admit, I am quite overwhelmed by the sheer variety of what I can choose from.

```
geckoview-exoplayer2-beta/
geckoview-exoplayer2-nightly/
geckoview-exoplayer2/
geckoview-nightly-arm64-v8a/
geckoview-nightly-armeabi-v7a/
geckoview-nightly-omni-arm64-v8a/
geckoview-nightly-omni-armeabi-v7a/
geckoview-nightly-omni-x86/
geckoview-nightly-omni-x86_64/
geckoview-nightly-omni/
geckoview-nightly-x86/
geckoview-nightly-x86_64/
geckoview-nightly/
geckoview-omni-arm64-v8a/
geckoview-omni-armeabi-v7a/
geckoview-omni-x86/
geckoview-omni-x86_64/
geckoview-omni/
geckoview-x86/
geckoview-x86_64/
geckoview/
...
```

Does anyone have any insight into what the differences are between all these builds?

Without any documentation, I am unsure which one an Android app should be using?

Comment: Anything with nightly means its the very head of their git repository.  Don't use them, they're for testing. I wouldn't use beta ones in a prod build either.   The last part of each is the ISA of the processor its for.  You'd use the x86_64 forx64 devices ( your emulators) and arm64-v8a for ARM devices (99.9% of all phones).

Comment: @GabeSechan I was planning on using the `omni` one. Or alternatively the very bottom one with no extension. I was going to do this because I had hoped they were the "universal" variant. You reckon this to be a bad idea?